# If $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint sets in $\mathbb R^d$, can we have $d(A,B)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint set in $\mathbb R^d$, can we have $d(A,B)=0$ ? Because I have a lemma that say that if $A$ is closed and $B$ compact, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $d(A,B)>0$. Therefore, I suppose that if $B$ is not compact, we can have $d(A,B)=0$, but I can't find an example. I was thinking about something like
$A=\{1,...,n,...\}$ and $B=\{1+\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{3}, 3+\frac{1}{4},...\}$ but those sets are not closed.

Comment: Your example is perfectly fine because those set are closed.

Comment: By "close" do you mean "closed"?  Your sets $A,B$ are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \mathbb N$ and let $B = \left\{n+\frac{1}{2n} :n\in \mathbb N\right\}$.  Then A and B are closed and disjoint, but $$\inf \{|a−b|:a \in A,b \in B\} = \inf \left | \frac{1}{2n}\right| = 0$$

**OR,**

Look at curve $xy=1$ and the $x$-axis.

Comment: are you sure that $\mathbb N$ is close ? (because if it is, my example work)

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb N$ is closed since $\mathbb N=\overline{\mathbb N}$. In general, every set of isolated point are closed.

Comment: @Rick Ofcourse just check that complement of $\mathbb N$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\geq 1,y=1/x\}$ and $B=\{(x,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\ge 1\}.$